# Boost serialization: from text_oarchive to xml_oarchive

Tags: serialization, boost, deserialization

Is it possible to translate from a text_oarchive to a xml_oarchive?

Answer (score 1):

Only if the serialization supported XML archives. In that case, read your archive with `text_iarchive` and serialize back into `xml_oarchive`.

The main requirement for XML archives is that all objects are named, so:

```
 boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(std::cout);
 std::string name = "sample";
 oa & name;
```

Needs to be

```
 boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(std::cout);
 std::string name = "sample";
 oa & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(name);
```

See also https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html#nvp